# Q5 from Nested SELECT Quiz from sqlzoo.net

Tags: sql

Q5. Select the code that would show the countries with a greater GDP than any country in Africa (some countries may have NULL gdp values).

I think the ans is

```
SELECT name FROM bbc
 WHERE gdp > ALL (SELECT gdp FROM bbc WHERE region = 'Africa' AND gdp<>NULL)
```

pick gdp from all countries in Africa which gdp is not null , and output the name of country who has a greater gdp than all Africa countries' gdp

but the correct ans from website is

```
SELECT name FROM bbc
 WHERE gdp > (SELECT MAX(gdp) FROM bbc WHERE region = 'Africa')
```

I know the bottom one is more simple,just pick the max gdp in Africa, but I cannot figure out why the top one is wrong ?

Comment: `AND gdp<>NULL` should be `AND gdp IS NO NULL`

Comment: so if I want to use <> ,I should write gdp<>'' ?

Comment: No, you need `gdp <> 0`  you can't compare a number with a string.

Comment: oh ic, but what if null gdp is blank not 0? Is it because NULL is not comparable in SQL ? So I can only use `AND gdp IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: There is no "blank" for numbers in SQL. It is either a number or it is NULL. Which question is that exactly? I can't find it on the SQLZoo website

Comment: It's Q5 MC from [link](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Nested_SELECT_Quiz)

Comment: I find a [website](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/) describing my problem , I think I find my ans already , Thank you so much helping me to point out the error from above